# Using If And Or Functions in VBA for refing to TextBox and Cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, textbox

I’m having trouble with the correct syntax of the following code. Hoping someone can help me. The range “Base_Point” refers to a particular cell (such as G3).

Here is what I am trying to express in my coding: If the value of TextBox6 = 1 AND Base_Point=1 or 3 or 5 or 7, then Z_End minus the value of TexBox5, otherwise Z_End plus the value of TextBox5.

```
IIF (AND(TextBox6.Value = 1) OR (Base_Point=1,Base_Point=3,Base_Point=5,Base_Point=7),Z_End-" & TextBox5 & " Z_End+" & TextBox5 & ")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a beginner, do not go for such "complex" codes. Keep it simple. Once you are better with coding then try that. Always believe in KISS principle.

Is this what you are trying? (Untested)

```
If TextBox1.Value = 1 Then
    Select Case Base_Point
        Case 1, 3, 5, 7
            '
            ' Do what you want if condition is true
            '
        Case Else
            '
            ' Do what you want if condition is false
            '
    End Select
Else
    '
    ' Do what you want if condition is false
    '
End If
```

Comment: Can you explain why you wrote `do not go for such "complex" codes` rather than `do not go for such complex codes`?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Sure. complexity in such a case depends on the level of the user. I can clearly see (I could be wrong) he is a novice and needs to start with something simple and then go for advanced versions. The emphasis on `"` was to indicate that for many of us here, using `IIF` is not at all complex but for a newbie, it can be. The intention was not to put down anyone here.

Comment: I was asking because the use of double-quotes like that means "I've used this word, but I don't actually think it's the right word". It's not for emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

If you need using `IIF`, try the next way, please:

```
Debug.Print IIf(TextBox6.Value = 1 And (Base_Point = 1 Or Base_Point = 3 _
                                    Or Base_Point = 5 Or Base_Point = 7), _
                                     Z_End - TextBox5, Z_End + TextBox5)
```

Otherwise, I would (also) use `Select Case`...